# Explanation of an integral formula over the $\mathcal S^2$ sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Let $\mathcal S^2:=\{x\in \mathbb R^3: \;\vert \vert x \vert \vert=1 \}$ and assume $f$ is a function of one variable, i.e $f(x)=f(x_1)$. I'm trying to understand the following formula:

> $\int_{\mathcal S^2} f(x) \;d\mathcal H^2(x)=2\pi \int_{-1}^1
>  f(x_1)\:dx_1$

It seems to me that polar coordinates are used here, however we are in a 3-dimensional space.

Is been a really long time since I encountered this kind of calculus and I feel I'm forgetting something essential here. I would appreciate any help in explaining why this formula holds true.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious, what is the $d\mathcal{H}^2(x)$ ? I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: You never explained where the notation came from.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I 'm sorry. It was part of some explicit computations my professor made. Not from a book, nor a specific course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result makes use of the interesting fact that in $3$ dimensions (and in $3$ dimensions only) slices of a sphere of equal width have equal surface area. So if you integrate a function of one Cartesian coordinate over the surface of the sphere, you can just integrate it over that coordinate, since slices of equal infinitesimal width $\mathrm dx_1$ have equal infinitesimal surface area (which here seems to be denoted by $\mathrm d\mathcal H^2$). You can then derive the factor $2\pi$ from the fact that integrating over $f(x_1)\equiv1$ must yield the surface area of the sphere, $4\pi$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I like the way you approached it but I don't really understand how the factor $2\pi$ appears. Why $f=1?$ Could you please write some more details?

Comment: @kaithkolesidou: Integrating $f=1$ over a domain yields the volume of that domain. Like when you integrate $1$ over $[a,b]$ you get $b-a$ and if you integrate $1$ over a square of side length $a$ you get $a^2$. If you integrate $1$ over the unit sphere you get its surface area $4\pi$. Since the integral on the left is $4\pi$ and the integral on the right is $2$, the factor proportionality must be $2\pi$.

Comment: But why should I set $f=1$? Is still a bit foggy to me... However thanks a lot once more for your time

Comment: @kaithkolesidou: Perhaps I didn't make the structure of the argument clear enough. Slices of equal width have equal surface area. That implies that the surface area is proportional to the width. We need to find the factor of proportionality. To do that, we can substitute any function for $f$ for which we know both integrals. We know them for $f=1$ because then they're just the volumes of the two domains, $4\pi$ and $2$, respectively. So we substitute $f=1$ to find that the constant of proportionality is $\frac{4\pi}2=2\pi$, and that then holds for all other functions, too.

Comment: this was what I needed! Nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

Set the $x_3$ axis to be the variable that $f$ depends on. We can use the known Jacobian from parametrising a sphere in angular [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (setting the radial coordinate to $1$). We get the integral

$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi}f(x_3)\sin\theta \:d\phi \:d\theta = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi}f(\cos\theta)\sin\theta \:d\phi \:d\theta = 2\pi\int_0^\pi f(\cos\theta)\sin\theta \:d\theta$$

Then use the substitution $x=\cos\theta$ to get the final expression:

$$2\pi\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\:dx$$

This works because we chose to rotate our coordinate system such that the function was not dependent on the $2\pi$ angular variable.